# Cannot read property "parameter" from undefined error with Logger.log

Tags: google-apps-script

I am getting "TypeError: Cannot read property "parameter" from undefined." when trying to log e.parameter properties. (I inserted the following lines in the contactMe() function)

```
Logger.log(e.parameter.textBox);
Logger.log(e.parameter);
```

The script otherwise works fine, any idea?

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var mainPanel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('mainPanel');
  app.add(mainPanel);

  mainPanel.add(app.createLabel('Enter your email to sign up'));

  var form = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  mainPanel.add(form);

  var email = app.createTextBox().setName('textBox').setId('textBox');
  form.add(email);

  var button = app.createButton('Sign up');
  form.add(button);

  var info = app.createLabel().setVisible(true).setId('info');
  mainPanel.add(info);

  //handler
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('contactMe').addCallbackElement(mainPanel);
  button.addClickHandler(handler);

  return app;
}

function contactMe(e){
 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

 Logger.log("testing");
 Logger.log(e.parameter);
 Logger.log(e.parameter.textBox);

 app.getElementById('textBox').setValue('').setStyleAttribute("color", "black");
 app.getElementById('info').setText('Thank you!').setStyleAttribute("color", "black");

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AqKSxC6f0Cc7dF9aT1lUeXFEcnR2eUFYRGs4Y1NiVVE')
                        .getSheets()[0];
 var range = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 2);

 var values = [[new Date(),e.parameter.textBox]];  
 range.setValues(values); 

 return app;   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested your exact code (except the sheet stuff) and it works nicely... except that the logger doesn't show anything when called from a handler function but that's a known issue...

I used the label to check the e.parameter value like this :

```
 app.getElementById('info').setText(e.parameter.textBox).setStyleAttribute("color", "black");
```

Comment: So Logger is bugged when called from a handler? Logger.log("message") seems to work thought. Any reason why it doesn't work with "e.parameter" as an argument?

Comment: I have nothing in the logger, the string doesn't either... see [issue 1502](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1502)

Comment: I suppose you have a typo in your script somewhere that you didn't reproduce in your question... the error message you mention could be coming from the e parameter itself... did you copy/paste ?

Answer (score 0):

A bit out of the box but i think it should work:

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  var mainPanel = app.createFormPanel;
  app.add(mainPanel);

  mainPanel.add(app.createLabel('Enter your email to sign up'));

  var form = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  mainPanel.add(form);

  var email = app.createTextBox().setName('textBox').setId('textBox');
  form.add(email);

  var button = app.createSubmitButton('Sign up');
  form.add(button);

  var info = app.createLabel().setVisible(true).setId('info');
  mainPanel.add(info);

  return app;
}

function doPost(e){
 var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

 //Logger wont work in uiApps
 //in Form panels the UI is cleared so you want to write a thank you note
 app.add(app.createLabel("Thanks"));


 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('0AqKSxC6f0Cc7dF9aT1lUeXFEcnR2eUFYRGs4Y1NiVVE')
                        .getSheets()[0];
 var range = ss.getRange(ss.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 2);

 var values = [[new Date(),e.parameter.textBox]];  
 range.setValues(values); 

 return app;
```

With kind regards,

Thomas van Latum

Comment: did you notice you have 2 doGet() in your script ? :-)

Comment: Yes just did.. should be doGet en doPost haha just changed it

Answer (score 0):

I just copy pasted your complete code made a spreadsheet and ran it.
It works just perfectly dont forget your } at the end.....